# segfault in libgnutls - Debian won't complete boot

Tags: debian, init, segmentation-fault

this problem occurs on Debian jessie x86 with systemd. It leads to an incomplete boot sequence on init 2 because network-manager won't start. it leaves the whole system unusable

```
NetworkManager[785]: segfault at e7394845 ip b74ab7a1 sp b7548810 error 7 in libgnutls-deb0.so.28.41.0[b746f000+13a000]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out, I interrupted an upgrade process earlier. I manually reinstalled the network manager package.